# Custom NER model - FAIL

Tags: nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am new to the NLP scene and am using `OpenNLP 1.5` for getting started.

I went through some the commands given in the documentation here:
https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html 
(I am using the command line interface to get started)

I used the already available sample models for experimenting with the different tools and finally decided to create a *custom NER model*.

I followed the instruction given in the aforementioned link.

Copied the sample sentences given into a `.train` file (I simply created a new file with that extension and pasted the contents into it):

```
<START:person> Pierre Vinken <END> , 61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
Mr . <START:person> Vinken <END> is chairman of Elsevier N.V. , the Dutch publishing group .
```

I used the following command to make the model:

```
bin/opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -model en-ner-person2.bin -lang en -data en-ner-person2.train -encoding UTF-8
```

The problem is that even though the model is getting created, it seems to be not working properly. Tested this by using the newly created model:
`bin/opennlp TokenNameFinder en-ner-person2.bin`

But when I input `Pierre Vinken`, it's not getting recognised as a person. I also tried creating the model from a `.txt` file with the exact same content, but that too failed.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA.

Comment: What is the output you get when you input `Pierre Vinken`? Have you tried inputting full sentences instead?

Comment: @NBartley Current output is just `Pierre Vinken`. I want `<START:person> Pierre Vinken <END>`.

Comment: @NBartley I haven't tried full sentences. When I tried just `Pierre Vinken` with the already available sample model, I got the expected output.

Comment: and what dies en-ner-person2.bin consist of? Is it en-ner-person.bin with added sentences, or is it completely new file?

Comment: @lejlot No, `en-ner-person2.bin` is a completely new model that is made using the `TokenNameFinderTrainer` command (given above) on the sample dataset consisting of 2 sentences (also given above).

Comment: I think that's the ticket -- the next line in the guide says that the training data should consist of at least 15,000 sentences.

Comment: Off topic: @Stack-Boi, I just noticed your question and I'm looking for people who are experienced in the development of NLP applications. I provide a framework which aims to make the development of custom NLP models easier. It is called [NLPf](https://gitlab.com/schrieveslaach/NLPf) and provides, for example, an annotation tool which makes the annotation process much easier. You can train your NLP model with `mvn install` and then, use it as single Maven dependency in your app. Do you have same time to experiment with the framework and answer a questionnaire for a scientific evaluation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short - you **cannot** expect statistical model to learn from just **two** sentences. Add 14,998 more and you are good to go.

> The training data should contain at least 15000 sentences to create a model which performs wel

CRF (Conditional Random Fields) are such statistical models, they do need **a lot** of data to figure out the rules of the game, they are not simply "remembering" what they seen during training phase, so even if you ask for something from the trianing set- they can fail to provide the answer.

Comment: Newbie question. Why is it like that? Wouldn't it be more efficient for the model to remember the words from the training set in addition to the machine learning process?

Comment: Is CRF the most popular statistical model? Where can a beginner learn more about it? What other statistical models are available?

Comment: It is this way because the way you actually learn good models is through complex statistical analysis, usually based on some differentiable cost function, "remembering" is not really compatible with such a paradigm, is simply a heuristic, nothing more. Machine learning (especially modern one) is about going away from heuristics and try to learn everything, instead of assuming that people know better what is the underlying mechanism. If you wanna learn more - go for coursera, there are plenty of courses about machine learning and/or NLP.

Comment: Are all NER models trained using the CRF algorithm? I saw that the Stanford NER uses this algorithm. But couldn't find the algorithm used by OpenNLP ... http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml

Comment: No, NER is a problem, and CRF is simply popular in the field, but far from being the only one.

Comment: I want to know the algorithm used by OpenNLP so that I can make sure that my model failed because of the lack of data and not because of unseen errors during the creation of the model.

Comment: **Every** statistical model will fail with 2 sentences. OpenNLP claims to be using "maximum entropy model" which is probably Maximum Entropy Markov Model (MEMM) which is a very similar thing to CRF (it is just about  normalizations used) or maybe even basic Logistic Regression with some context data as input (still, same argument applies).